# Colorizing output while using pr

Tags: bash, colors, ascii, gnu-coreutils

I'm running some commands that returns lists of strings and getting their output in different variables.

Then I want to write the different command's output side by side. For this, I'm using `pr`.

A sample code of what I'm doing is:

```
#!/bin/bash

i1=$(echo -e "test11\ntest12")
i2=$(echo -e "test21\ntest22\ntest23")
i3=$(echo -e "test31\ntest32\ntest33")

pr -T -m <(echo "$i1") <(echo "$i2") <(echo "$i3")
```

which give the nice output:

```
test11          test21          test31
test12          test22          test32
                test23          test33
```

But as soon as I try to colorize the output (using ASCII codes), I'm starting to get bad aligned columns.

```
#!/bin/bash

i1=$(echo -e "test11\n\033[1mtest12\033[0m")
i2=$(echo -e "test21\ntest22\ntest23")
i3=$(echo -e "test31\ntest32\ntest33")

pr -T -m <(echo "$i1") <(echo "$i2") <(echo "$i3")
```

gives

```
test11          test21          test31
test12      test22          test32
                test23          test33
```

with the "test12" (word of the first column and second row) colorized as expected, but the other columns misaligned.

I tried to also use ASCII codes to move the cursor back to its original position, but it didn't worked as expected.

Any ideas on how could I make the colors work with `pr`? Alternatively, any ideas on how I can print the three colorized files in three aligned columns?

Comment: are all strings (`test` in this case) going to be of the same length; what would you expect as output for `i1=$(echo -e "test\ntester\ntestinginginging")` ?

Comment: The output is generated by a third program. I have to check, but I think each column will be of the same length, while different columns can be of different lengths, and lengths will change in each execution.

Comment: if all values in one column (aka, in the same variable) are going to be the same length, see Cyrus' answer re: use `paste`; if  values in one column (aka, one variable) can be of different lengths then you need to a) find the length of the value, b) find the length of the printable/viewable value and c) use these 2 lengths to determine numeric offset (`#`) in a `printf %-#s` call; this could be done via bash commands or via a single `awk` call (likely faster for a large volume of data); I can dig up a `awk` solution if you verify variable widths ...

Comment: @Cyrus, I will do that once I have the opportunity to check the answers at work, on Monday.

Comment: @markp, I can do all the calculations manually, I just wanted to do all this hassle automatically with some existing tool.

Comment: I updated the question with some extra details regarding column lengths.

Comment: I'm not aware of any commands that automatically adjust the output based on a varying number of non-printable (format) characters; I'm thinking the only option is to manually calculate the formats (eg, for `printf`) for each field

Comment: So far, I implemented a set of loops with printf to generate the three rectangular blocks with the same lengths and joined them with paste. But it is really a long and error-prone work where an existing tool could make a big difference.